# Powershell script to create Contacts inside Exchange account?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

Is it possible with Powershell to create Contacts inside a Exchange account?
Im not talking about creating a Contact in Active Directory, but a contact in the Exchange account there will be visable by Outlook, Webmail, and Mobile sync.

The reason for this, is that a customer wants a easy way to deploy some static adresses, without the use of using contacts in the Global Address list.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the EWS Managed API library with Powershell for this, I have a module on GitHub which should work okay https://github.com/gscales/Powershell-Scripts/tree/master/EWSContacts

Cheers
Glen